# Generar archivo xml en C#

Tags: c#, xml

en vista de que mi consulta anterior .. supongo que no fue vista. pregunto de nuevo. Aclaro igual que llevo con esto unas dos semanas y no me manejo mucho con c#. tengo que generar un archivo xml con datos desde una Base de datos, la estructura de este archivo es la siguiente:

```html
//documento creado en C# para la creacion de un documento xml
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Documento",
                    new XAttribute("id", "000001"),

                    new XElement("Signers",
                        new XElement("Signer",
                            new XAttribute("Type", "Rut")
                        )
                   ),

                    new XElement("Content",
                        new XElement("sve",
                            new XElement("Documento",
                                new XAttribute("ID", "Documento101"),
                                new XAttribute("xmlns", ""),
                                new XComment("Lo que es la cabecera del documento"),
                                from Cabecera in Cabecera.GetCabecera()
                                select new XElement("cabecera",
                                       new XElement("garantia_numero", Cabecera.nUsuarioRutNumero[0]),
                                       new XElement("informacion_adicional", Cabecera.InformacionAdicional),
                                       new XElement("procedencia_codigo", Cabecera.ProcedenciaCodigo),
                                        new XElement("numero_provisorio", Cabecera.NumeroProvisorio),
                                        new XElement("numero_interno_usuario", Cabecera.NumeroInternoUsuario),
                                        new XElement("pais_codigo", Cabecera.PaisCodigo),
                                        new XElement("glosa", Cabecera.Glosa),
                                        new XElement("usuario_rut_numero", Cabecera.UsuarioRutNumero),
                                        new XElement("usuario_rut_dv", Cabecera.UsuarioRutDv),
                                        new XElement("puerto_embarque_codigo", Cabecera.PuertoEmbarqueCodigo),
                                        new XElement("tipo_tramite_codigo", Cabecera.TipoTramiteCodigo),
                                        new XElement("ubicacion_destino_codigo", Cabecera.UbicacionDestinoCodigo),
                                        new XElement("moneda_codigo", Cabecera.MonedaCodigo),
                                        new XElement("medio_transporte_codigo", Cabecera.MedioTransporteCodigo),
                                        new XElement("pais_origen", Cabecera.PaisOrigen),
                                        new XElement("valor_fob", Cabecera.ValorFob),
                                        new XElement("valor_flete", Cabecera.ValorFlete),
                                        new XElement("valor_seguro", Cabecera.ValorSeguro),
                                        new XElement("valor_cif", Cabecera.ValorCif),
                                        new XElement("clausula", Cabecera.Clausula),
                                        new XElement("transbordo_nacional", Cabecera.TransbordoNacional),
                                        new XElement("transbordo_extranjero", Cabecera.TransbordoExtranjero)
                                ),
                                new XComment("Los Documentos adjuntos"),
                                new XComment("Pueden tener muchos documentos adjuntos"),
                                new XElement("documentosadjuntos",
                                    from DocAd in DocumentosAdjuntos.GetDocumentosAd()
                                    select new XElement("documentoadjunto",
                                        new XElement("tipo_codigo", DocAd.TipoCodigo),
                                        new XElement("numero_documento", DocAd.NDocumento),
                                        new XElement("fecha_documento", DocAd.FDocumento),
                                        new XElement("emisor", DocAd.Emisor),
                                        new XElement("aduana_origen_codigo", DocAd.AduanaORCod),
                                        new XElement("rut_numero", DocAd.RutNum),
                                        new XElement("rut_dv", DocAd.RutDV)
                                    )
                                ),
                                new XComment("Los bustos que pueda tener el documento"),
                                new XElement("bultos",
                                    new XComment("El o los bultos"),
                                    for (int i = 0; Bultos.PesoBulto.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            new XElement("bulto",
                                            new XElement("tipo_bulto_codigo", Bultos.TipoBultoCodigo[i]),
                                            new XElement("cantidad_bulto", Bultos.CantidadBulto[i]),
                                            new XElement("peso_bulto", Bultos.PesoBulto[i]),
                                            new XElement("descripcion_bulto", Bultos.DescripcionBulto[i]),
                                        }
                                        
                                    

                                 , new XElement("contenedores",
                                     //se crea un contenedor - puede tener más pero va en un for
                                     from cont in Contenedores.GetContenedores()

                                     select new XElement("contenedor",
                                                 new XElement("contenedor_tipo_codigo", cont.ContTipCodigo),
                                                 new XElement("contenedor_numero", cont.ContTipCodigo)
                                         )
                                 )

                                 /*new XElement("detalle",
                                    from item in Items.GetItems()
                                    select new XElement("item",
                                            new XElement("nro_item", item.NItem),
                                            new XElement("codigo_arancelario", item.CodArancelario),
                                            new XElement("cantidad_unidad_medida_arancelaria", item.CantUniMedArancelaria),
                                            new XElement("unidad_medida_codigo", item.UMedCodigo),
                                            new XElement("cantidad", item.Cantidad),
                                            new XElement("total_valor_cif", item.TotValCIF),
                                            new XElement("descriptores",
                                            //se crea un descriptor - puede tener más pero va en un for
                                            from des in Descriptores.GetDescriptores()
                                            select new XElement("descriptor",
                                                    new XElement("descriptor_codigo", des.descriptor_codigo),
                                                    new XElement("descriptor_valor", des.descriptor_valor)
                                            )//por dscriptor
                                        )//Descriptores
                                    )//item
                                )//detalle*/
                            ),//documento
                            new XElement("URI"),
                            new XElement("TmstFirma"),
                            new XElement("Signature",
                                new XAttribute("xmlns", "")
                            ),
                            new XElement("SignedInfo",
                                new XElement("CanonicalizationMethod",
                                    new XAttribute("Algorithm", "")
                                ),
                                new XElement("SignatureMethod",
                                    new XAttribute("Algorithm", "")
                                ),
                                new XElement("Reference",
                                    new XAttribute("URI", ""),
                                    new XElement("DigestMethod",
                                        new XAttribute("Algorithm", "")
                                    ),
                                    new XElement("DigestValue")
                                )//reference
                            ), //signedInfo
                            new XElement("SignatureValue"),
                            new XElement("KeyInfo",
                                new XElement("KeyValue",
                                    new XElement("RSAKeyValue",
                                        new XElement("Modulus"),
                                        new XElement("Exponent")
                                    )//RSAkeyvalue
                                ),//KeyValue
                                new XElement("X509Data",
                                    new XElement("X509Certificate")
                                )
                            )//KeyInfo
                        )//sve
                        )//content
                    )//documento
                )); //xDocument
```

tengo que generar una cabecera, documentoAdjunto y otras, pero para el caso voy a poner el código para el DocumentoAdjunto.cs:

tengo mis variables, y genero de forma manual mi lista con los datos que quiero que muestre, mi consulta es si se puede generar esto de otra forma, agregarle un ciclo for para que se genere de forma automática usando base de datos.

```html
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class DocumentosAdjuntos
    {
        public int TipoCodigo { get; set; }
        public string NDocumento { get; set; }
        public string FDocumento {get;set;}
        public string Emisor { get; set; }
        public string AduanaORCod { get; set; }
        public int RutNum { get; set; }
        public string RutDV { get; set; }

        public static List<DocumentosAdjuntos> GetDocumentosAd(){
            List<DocumentosAdjuntos> LstDocumentosAd = new List<DocumentosAdjuntos>()
            {
                new DocumentosAdjuntos{TipoCodigo = 1, NDocumento= "001", FDocumento = "2018-12-15", Emisor="Josecito", AduanaORCod="CVR-567", RutNum=16163632, RutDV="k"},
                new DocumentosAdjuntos{TipoCodigo = 1, NDocumento= "001", FDocumento = "2018-12-15", Emisor="Josecito", AduanaORCod="CVR-567", RutNum=16163632, RutDV="k"},
                new DocumentosAdjuntos{TipoCodigo = 1, NDocumento= "001", FDocumento = "2018-12-15", Emisor="Josecito", AduanaORCod="CVR-567", RutNum=16163632, RutDV="k"},
                new DocumentosAdjuntos{TipoCodigo = 1, NDocumento= "001", FDocumento = "2018-12-15", Emisor="Josecito", AduanaORCod="CVR-567", RutNum=16163632, RutDV="k"}
            
            };

            return LstDocumentosAd;
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Primero y principal, si esta es la misma pregunta que la anterior, entonces no tenes que duplicarla, si no seguir sobre la anterior, ya que en ella hay informacion agregada por vos y por quienes comentaron que es importante. Tambien pensa, que tal vez lo que pedis no tenga una respuesta clara, o la pregunta no sea clara, o simplemente lo que pedis no se puede hacer. Ahora vamos por el primer punto. Es la misma pregunta? la informacion parece ser la misma.

Comment: Yo de tu pregunta anterior, nunca entendi el sentido de la misma. Que importa de donde vienen los datos (manual o una base de datos). Solamente vas llenando la estructura como queres. Cual es el problema puntual?

Comment: Mi problema es que estoy generando la lista de forma manual, tengo que poner el new DocumentosAdjuntos y llenar todos los campos. Lo que necesito es poder aplicar un ciclo for o algo para que se vaya haciendo de forma automática. lo otro que estaba pensando es que el tipo de lista que estoy usando no sea el adecuado para el caso, pero ahí ya me pierdo

Comment: Vuelvo a lo mismo de antes. Sigo sin entender tu problema puntual. Cual seria el problema con el for? Tal vez no estes explicando bien esto, o tengas lo que se suele llamar un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/324). Empieza eliminando esta pregunta, trata de arreglar la anterior (esta se va a cerrar por duplicada) y trabajemos en lo que tenes ahi. Tambien, podes probar que hablemos de tu problema en el [chat]. Pero tene en cuenta que lo primero que tenes que hacer, es reducir el mismo a un problema que podamos reproducir. mira [mcve]

Comment: ok, voy a volver a plantear mi problema y tratar de explicar con código lo que necesito y que me falla. gracias